# Design a tank circuit for class C power amplifier using ADS

Tags: rf, circuit-design, high-frequency, power-amplifier

I am trying to figure out the best values for the tank circuit values (L and C) in order to compare the amplifier's efficiency with the output power
I have chosen the tank value L1 and C7 to resonate at 1GHz (see attached), you know we can choose different values for L and C to be resonating at the 1 GHz frequency. What is the most efficient way of selecting the L and C values for such a case?

[image: Class-C PA schematic]
[image: Current & voltage output without the tank cicruit]
[image: Current & voltage output with a tank circuit]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a quarterwave stripline, the upper end tied to battery and a fine low ESR RF-rated capacitor, as your resonator. At exactly quarter-wave, the lower end, tied to your collector, will exhibit infinite impedance just like your ideal LC.

Comment: Should the capacitor be connected to stripline as bypass cap?
In case of changing the operating freq. from 1GHz to 10GHz, does that will cause any problem?

Comment: Yes, the cap is connected at the (upper, VDD, power supply) end as bypass capacitor. At 10GHz, with wavelength of 3cm, quarter wave of 8mm, achieving a precision resonance may be tough. At higher frequencies, ceramic substrates with final-tuning by abrasive air-driven particle etching was used, back in the days.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the most efficient way of selecting the L and C values for
>   such a case?

On the face of it there are a myriad different combinations but, to narrow this down you need to factor in the load impedance and the target Q factor for the circuit. I do not know what your expected Q is and all I can see is a 252 ohm load resistor that may (or may not) be accurate. The lower that this resistor value is; the lower the Q and the less the gain of your circuit.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Parallel_RLC_circuit) explains what Q will be for a parallel RLC circuit: -

$$Q = R\sqrt{\dfrac{C}{L}}$$

So, once you have calculated what your Q is then you can calculate L and C. If you need help understanding what your frequency response will look like when you vary the values, [this site](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20BPF/RCL%20BPF.html) has an interactive calculator for a band-pass filter. It's not precisely the same configuration of R, L and C in your circuit but it comes up with the goods for the Q factor: -

[image]

For 1 GHz I've chosen an inductor of 5 nH, a capacitor of 5 pF and a load (or drive) resistor of 100 ohms. This produces a Q of 3.16.

> I have chosen the tank value L1 and C7 to resonate at 1GHz

Your schematic shows C at 25 uF and L at 100 mH. This has a resonant frequency 100.65 Hz i.e. nowhere near 1 GHz.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your help. In case I managed to choose the tank circuit components correctly, should I expect the output voltage and current to be sinusoide??

Comment: The L and C form a bandpass filter and if the transistor introduces distortion then the sinewave voltage will not be perfect.